# Proving a distribution limit with a non-integrable part in its integrand without Riemann-Lebesgue's lemma

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, distribution-theory

Let $f_t(x) = \frac{\sin tx}x$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Further, consider a test function $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ with $\operatorname{supp} \varphi \subseteq [-R, R]$ for some $R>0.$

I have proved that $$\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]} f_t(x) \; \mathrm dx \to 0$$ when considering the limit $t\to \infty$. I want to prove $$\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]} f_t(x) \varphi(x) \; \mathrm dx \to 0$$ from this.

The problem is that $f_t \not\to 0$, so dominated convergence doesn't work. Moreover; $f_t$ is not absolutely integrable and, even more so, the integral $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb R} f_t(x) \; \mathrm dx$ only exists in a generalized Riemann sense (with an undefined Lebesgue integral).

Can I prove this without using Riemann-Lebesgue's lemma (as they do [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009880/calculating-lim-lambda-rightarrow-infty-t-frac-sin-lambda-xx-in)), if the limit $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]} f_t(x) \; \mathrm dx \to 0$ is known?

If it is helpful we can also assume that $\displaystyle\int_\Omega f_t(x) \; \mathrm dx \to 0$ for any closed subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb R$ with $0 \not\in \Omega$, as in the case for $f_t(x) = \frac{\sin tx}x$.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result integrating by parts. For $\varepsilon<R$
$$
\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]} f_t(x)\, \varphi(x) \, {\mathrm d}x =\int_{-R}^{-\varepsilon}f_t(x)\, \varphi(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_
{\varepsilon}^Rf_t(x\,) \varphi(x)\,\mathrm dx.
$$
Now
\begin{align}
\int_
{\varepsilon}^Rf_t(x)\, \varphi(x)\,\mathrm dx&=\int_{\varepsilon}^R\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}\,\sin(t\,x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=-\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}\,\frac{\cos(t\,x)}{t}\Bigr|_\varepsilon^R+\int_{\varepsilon}^R\Bigl(\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}\Bigr)'\frac{\cos(t\,x)}{t}\,\mathrm dx.
\end{align}

Comment: Can you generalize this to the case you don't know what $f_t$ is, i.e. just knowing $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]} f_t(x) \; \mathrm dx \to 0$?

Comment: No without further conditions. Consider for instance $f_t(x)=t\sin x\chi_{[-\pi,\pi]}(x)$. Then $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]} f_t(x)\, {\mathrm d}x=0$ for all $t$, but nothing can be said about $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]} f_t(x)\, \varphi(x) \, {\mathrm d}x$.

Comment: I might add this to the original question, but we also know that the integral over an arbitrary closed interval not containing 0 tends to zero as $t$ gets large.